# Visual Studio Code formatting void html elements

Tags: html, parsing, angular, formatting, visual-studio-code

I have an issue formatting custom angular 2 components.
Closing tag is indented with two extra spaces, so are the following tags.

Example:

```
<cb-input *ngIf="isEndUser"
          label="Cognome"
          name="rma-cli-cognome"
          [(ngModel)]="rma.BP.NAME"
          placeholder="Inserire il cognome"
          required
          minlength="2">
  </cb-input>
  <cb-input *ngIf="isEndUser"*
```

If I self close the tag ( `<cb-input/>` ) formatting works fine but it breaks my angular 2 template.

Is formatting/parsing of void, not self closing, custom tags supported?
It used to work in previous releases.

Version 1.9.1 on Windows.